# Python Winerror 193 when switch to 64 bit

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit

I switched from a 32 bit version of python to a 64 bit version because 32 bit doesn't support tensorflow.

**The problem:**

My script wouldn't run in my 3.6 python environment because i get the following message:

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Gebruiker/Documents/SC2 AI/SCAI deeplearning.py', wdir='C:/Users/Gebruiker/Documents/SC2 AI')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Gebruiker/Documents/SC2 AI/SCAI deeplearning.py", line 1, in 
    import keras

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from . import utils

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from . import np_utils

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 6, in 
    import numpy as np

File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 140, in 
    from . import _distributor_init

File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py", line 26, in 
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

**OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing**

The error is in dutch and means: [winerror 193] 1 is not a valid win32 application.
The strange thing is that the exact same script will run in python 3.7 but unfortunately some of the essential features of this script are not supported by python 3.7....

Of course I have already searched on the forum but I can't seem to find a solution to this specific problem.

**Question**

Can someone help me out and explain what I can do so that my script runs on a 3.6 version of python and 64 bits?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages, include everything that is relevant (including the complete error traceback) as text in the question itself.

Comment: The error indicates ctypes is being used to load a 32-bit DLL in 64-bit Python. You need the 64-bit version of that DLL.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Does that mean that my python library is still in 32 bit? that would be weird since my python is in 64 bits and they are both re-installed at the same time with anaconda.

Comment: No, it probably means that your Python 3.6 is 64-bit but the version of `numpy` in your 3.6 environment is 32-bit.

Comment: Indeed making sure numpy is 64 bit solved this problem!